# How can i delete particular field in json array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
[
  {

    "user_pass": "$PBa5$.cxL91nBU5cG4gqhNp8mWZoJgFY/",
    "user_mobile":"1234567890",
    "user_nicename": "abc",
    "user_email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0

  },
  {

    "user_pass": "$P$BwfQRzajR6R9eLeZbPnTgfQfsfPDhK0",
    "user_mobile":"0987654321",
    "user_nicename": "cdv",
    "user_email": "cdv@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0
  },
  {

    "user_pass": "$P$Be15Zwqze.9OxoYfTOMd0WjlgXO7xe.",
    "user_mobile":"5432167890",
    "user_nicename": "zxc",
    "user_email": "zxc@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0
  }
 ]
```

Above is my data.

1 . I  want to delete user_pass field in every object.

2 . I want to use user_mobile as user_pass

my expectation result:

below i have mentioned my final result

```
[
  {

    "user_pass": "1234567890",
    "user_mobile":"1234567890",
    "user_nicename": "abc",
    "user_email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0

  },
  {

    "user_pass": "0987654321",
    "user_mobile":"0987654321",
    "user_nicename": "cdv",
    "user_email": "cdv@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0
  },
  {

    "user_pass": "5432167890",
    "user_mobile":"5432167890",
    "user_nicename": "zxc",
    "user_email": "zxc@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0
  }
 ]
```

any one help me out i am new to this technology .

Comment: Use simple and humble `for` loop, iterate array and update `user_pass`.

Comment: can you please help me out @Satpal

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/as2kg67u/ `for (var i in users) {
        users[i].user_pass= users[i].user_mobile;
 }`

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through the object array and reference `user_mobile` to `user_pass`.

```
var arr = [...data...];

arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.user_pass = obj.user_mobile;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var arr=[ { "user_pass": "$PBa5$.cxL91nBU5cG4gqhNp8mWZoJgFY/", "user_mobile":"1234567890", "user_nicename": "abc", "user_email": "abc@gmail.com", "user_status": 0 }, { "user_pass": "$P$BwfQRzajR6R9eLeZbPnTgfQfsfPDhK0", "user_mobile":"0987654321", "user_nicename": "cdv", "user_email": "cdv@gmail.com", "user_status": 0 }, { "user_pass": "$P$Be15Zwqze.9OxoYfTOMd0WjlgXO7xe.", "user_mobile":"5432167890", "user_nicename": "zxc", "user_email": "zxc@gmail.com", "user_status": 0 } ];
arr.forEach(function(a){
a.user_pass=a.user_mobile;
})
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{

  "user_pass": "$PBa5$.cxL91nBU5cG4gqhNp8mWZoJgFY/",
  "user_mobile": "1234567890",
  "user_nicename": "abc",
  "user_email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "user_status": 0

}, {

  "user_pass": "$P$BwfQRzajR6R9eLeZbPnTgfQfsfPDhK0",
  "user_mobile": "0987654321",
  "user_nicename": "cdv",
  "user_email": "cdv@gmail.com",
  "user_status": 0
}, {

  "user_pass": "$P$Be15Zwqze.9OxoYfTOMd0WjlgXO7xe.",
  "user_mobile": "5432167890",
  "user_nicename": "zxc",
  "user_email": "zxc@gmail.com",
  "user_status": 0
}];

var newData = data.map(function(item) {
  return {
    user_pass: item.user_mobile,
    user_mobile: item.user_mobile,
    user_nicename: item.user_nicename,
    user_email: item.user_email,
    user_status: item.user_status
  };
});

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568946/how-to-pass-multiple-values-while-uploading-image-to-serverfile-upload-with-ang

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it in an immutable way you could map over the array and Assign all the object properties to new objects.

```js
const data = [
  {

    "user_pass": "$PBa5$.cxL91nBU5cG4gqhNp8mWZoJgFY/",
    "user_mobile":"1234567890",
    "user_nicename": "abc",
    "user_email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0

  },
  {

    "user_pass": "$P$BwfQRzajR6R9eLeZbPnTgfQfsfPDhK0",
    "user_mobile":"0987654321",
    "user_nicename": "cdv",
    "user_email": "cdv@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0
  },
  {

    "user_pass": "$P$Be15Zwqze.9OxoYfTOMd0WjlgXO7xe.",
    "user_mobile":"5432167890",
    "user_nicename": "zxc",
    "user_email": "zxc@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0
  }
 ]

const newData = data.map(user => 
  Object.assign({}, user, {
    user_pass: user.user_mobile
  }))

console.log(data)
console.log(newData)
console.log(data === newData)
console.log(data[0] === newData[0])
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i in users) { users[i].user_pass= users[i].user_mobile; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

```js
var obj = [
  {

    "user_pass": "$PBa5$.cxL91nBU5cG4gqhNp8mWZoJgFY/",
    "user_mobile":"1234567890",
    "user_nicename": "abc",
    "user_email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0

  },
  {

    "user_pass": "$P$BwfQRzajR6R9eLeZbPnTgfQfsfPDhK0",
    "user_mobile":"0987654321",
    "user_nicename": "cdv",
    "user_email": "cdv@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0
  },
  {

    "user_pass": "$P$Be15Zwqze.9OxoYfTOMd0WjlgXO7xe.",
    "user_mobile":"5432167890",
    "user_nicename": "zxc",
    "user_email": "zxc@gmail.com",
    "user_status": 0
  }
 ]

for(var i =0 ; i < obj.length; i++){
     obj[i].user_pass= obj[i].user_mobile
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I still don't understand why we use for loops on arrays/collections these days, when we have tons of high order functions implemented in Array.prototype

Comment: stick to your roots

Comment: That's why we don't evolve, and that's why we can't move to better programming. When people think like this. I dare you to stick to your roots for the next ten years and I guarantee you will become a dinosaur

Comment: Lol relax... For loop gives you more flexibility...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568946/how-to-pass-multiple-values-while-uploading-image-to-serverfile-upload-with-ang