# How to pass multiple values while uploading image to server(File Upload with AngularJS and NodeJS)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Client side:

I have done file upload with AngularJS and NodeJS it's working but while uploading file i need to pass 'name' and 'email' to server.

Server side:

After uploading file into folder i need to save file path, name and email into database. How can i do this?

```js
angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload'])
.controller('MyCtrl',['Upload','$window',function(Upload,$window){
    var vm = this;
    vm.submit = function(){ //function to call on form submit
        if (vm.upload_form.file.$valid && vm.file) { //check if from is valid
            vm.upload(vm.file); //call upload function
        }
    }
    
    vm.upload = function (file) {
  
  console.log(vm.name);
  console.log(vm.email);
  
  
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
            data:{file:file} //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
        }).then(function (resp) { //upload function returns a promise
            if(resp.data.error_code === 0){ //validate success
                $window.alert('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ');
            } else {
                $window.alert('an error occured');
            }
        }, function (resp) { //catch error
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
            $window.alert('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        }, function (evt) { 
            console.log(evt);
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
            vm.progress = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% '; // capture upload progress
        });
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/danialfarid-angular-file-upload/12.2.13/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-file-upload/2.4.1/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Home</title>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="fileUpload">
  <h1>Angular Node File Upload</h1>
        <form  ng-controller="MyCtrl as up" name="up.upload_form">
               
   name 
   <input type="text" ng-model="up.name"><br> <br>
   email 
   <input type="text" ng-model="up.email"><br> 
   Image 
            <input 
                type="file" 
                ngf-select 
                ng-model="up.file" 
                name="file" 
                ngf-max-size="20MB" 
                />
            Image thumbnail: <img style="width:100px;" ng-show="!!up.file" ngf-thumbnail="up.file || '/thumb.jpg'"/>
            <i ng-show="up.upload_form.file.$error.required">*required</i><br>
            <i ng-show="up.upload_form.file.$error.maxSize">File too large 
            {{up.file.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 20M</i>
           <!--  Multiple files
            <div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="up.files" ngf-multiple="true">Select</div>
            Drop files: <div ngf-drop ng-model="up.files" class="drop-box">Drop</div> --><br> 
            <button type="submit" ng-click="up.submit()">submit</button>
            <p>{{up.progress}}</p>
        </form>
 </body>
 
</html>
```

Backend code:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

app.use(function(req, res, next) { //allow cross origin requests
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

/** Serving from the same express Server
No cors required */
app.use(express.static('../client'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());  

var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1]);
    }
});

var upload = multer({ //multer settings
                storage: storage
            }).single('file');

/** API path that will upload the files */
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
             res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
             return;
        }
         res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
    });
});

app.listen('3000', function(){
    console.log('running on 3000...');
});
```

i tried like this

```
Upload.upload({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
        data:{file:file, name:vm.name, email:vm.email} //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
    })
```

backend

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.file);
      upload(req,res,function(err){
            if(err){
                 res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
                 return;
            }
             res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
        });
    });
```

in front end(angular)i am getting value what ever i entered in form but backend(nodejs) i am getting undefined  value
[image]
 [image]

Comment: Are you using Cloudinary for file upload, also can we see your upload method

Answer (score 1):

You need to amend your angular code to send the extra info in the data of the request

```
Upload.upload({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
        data:{file:file, name:vm.name, email:vm.email} //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
    })
```

Then in your backend code you can reference this on the body of the request

```
req.body.name
req.body.email
```

Comment: i am getting undefined in my console(backend)

Comment: sorry should be vm.name and vm.email.  changed my answer

Comment: yeah i modified still i am getting undefined only

Comment: can you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can add a file property that will hold the `file` and update the `data property to contain email and name` inside the `Upload.upload` object. This way you can get them easily at the server side.

**Note**: I have updated my answer, I wrapped all the values `Angular view`is emitting inside a `params` object. I also changed angular-ng-upload CDN wasn't working on codepen. You should also load `Angular.js` first.

**view**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="fileUpload">
        <h1>Angular Node File Upload</h1>
        <form  ng-controller="MyCtrl as up" name="up.upload_form">

            name    
            <input type="text" ng-model="up.params.name"><br> <br>
            email   
            <input type="text" ng-model="up.params.email"><br> 
            Image 
            <input 
                type="file" 
                ngf-select 
                ng-model="up.params.file" 
                name="file" 
                ngf-max-size="20MB" 
                />
            Image thumbnail: <img style="width:100px;" ng-show="!!up.params.file" ngf-thumbnail="up.params.file || '/thumb.jpg'"/>
            <i ng-show="up.upload_form.params.file.$error.required">*required</i><br>
            <i ng-show="up.upload_form.params.file.$error.maxSize">File too large 
            {{up.params.file.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 20M</i>
           <!--  Multiple files
            <div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="up.files" ngf-multiple="true">Select</div>
            Drop files: <div ngf-drop ng-model="up.files" class="drop-box">Drop</div> --><br> 
            <button type="submit" ng-click="up.submit()">submit</button>
            <p>{{up.progress}}</p>
            <p>{{up.params}}{{up.params.file.size}}</p>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

**Angular**

```
var vm = this;

vm.submit = function(){ 
   if (vm.upload_form.file.$valid && vm.params.file) {
       console.log(vm.params)
       vm.upload(vm.params); // Pass the `vm.params` object.
   }
 }

vm.upload = function (params) {

    console.log(params.name); // params.name should be available
    console.log(params.email); // params.email should be available
    console.log(params.file); // params.file should be available

    Upload.upload({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload',
      file: params.file,   // Image to upload
      data: {
        name: params.name,
        email: params.email
      } 
    })
}
```

**Node.js/express**

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(req.body.data)); // email and name here
    console.log(req.files.file); // file object

    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
             res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
             return;
        }
         res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
    });
});
```

Comment: req.body.data m getting undefined

Comment: i am getting like this {}

Comment: The Angular part can you log the form object that you are getting before making the API call

Comment: angular i got value but in server side i am getting undefined

Comment: You paste a pseudo code of what you get from the angular view here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132893/discussion-between-cool-and-akinjide).

Comment: can you please help me out

Comment: Maybe a remote peer session?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if my answer will help you. But you can add in your data the name and the email.

```
Upload.upload({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
            data:{file:file,name:"putHeretheName",email:"putHereTheMail"} //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
        }
```

Then server side you can create a function or complete your actual "/upload" with a query that save in your bdd what you want. You just have to get the name of the path created and then do the save in case of your upload is successful.

Maybe this e.g will help you more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-upload

Comment: can you please help me out

Comment: I never used the lib multer, so I need more description to try to help you. Cause my link explain how to do what you want and if you say it's doesn't work, I need more info about the error.

Comment: i followed this tutorial https://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/12/07/file-upload-with-angularjs-and-nodejs/

Comment: So did you tried to put the name and the email inside you data that you will send to your server ?

Comment: server side i am getting value undefined

Comment: Upload.upload({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
            data:{file:file,name:"toto",lastname:"titi"} //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
        }).then(function (resp) { .....}

Comment: try this, and show me what there is inside your data that you receive server side please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132934/discussion-between-cool-and-nathan-meunier).